# SQL Server How to always rollback the entire transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, testing, transactions

I have a somewhat unusual need for my transaction handling.

I am working on a mutation test framework for SQL Server, for this I need to run my tests inside a transaction, so that the database always is in the state it started when the tests finish.

However I have the problem that users can code inside the test procedures and may call `rollback transaction` that may or may not be inside a (nested) transaction (savepoint).

high level it looks like this

```
start transaction
initialize test
run test with user code
   may or may not contain:
      - start tran
      - start tran savename
      - commit tran
      - commit tran savename
      - rollback tran
      - rollback tran savename
output testresults
rollback transaction
```

Is there a way to make sure I can at last always roll back to the initial state? I have to take in account that users can call stored procedures/triggers that maybe nested and can all contain transaction statements. With all my solutions the moment a user uses rollback tran in their test code they escape the transaction and not everything will be cleaned

What I want is that if a user calls rollback only their part of the transaction is rolled back and my transaction that I start before the initialization of the test is still intact.

If it is possible I want to prevent to force my users to use a transaction template that uses savepoints when a transaction already exists.

Comment: A `rollback tran` always roll back the entire transaction. If your users are allowed to call that, they are allowed to roll back your transaction. There is nothing you can do about this. Code that does it is a PITA to use. One should write their code in a way that does not roll back transactions not started by it.

Comment: A possible alternative is to use [database snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server) to return the database to any desired state irrespective of what happened in transactions. From SQL Server 2016 SP1 onwards these are available in all editions; prior to that they're only available in Enterprise and Developer.

Comment: how efficient are snapshots compared to transactions? It seems that this might be a solution if it can be made and restored automaticly

Comment: That would greatly depend on what your transactions are doing; you'd need to test. It's been a while since I actually tested this setup. Reverting to a snapshot is certainly faster than backup/restore (even an incremental one) but not faster than very trivial SQL statements. The major benefit is not being dependent on the exact undertakings of the code. Personally I value reliability of tests much higher than the speed at which they run. You can always scale up running tests by throwing more resources at it (in this case, multiple DBs and parallelism), but reliability is not so lucky.

Comment: As I read right now snapshots have problems when trying to create them automatticly, since I can't influence install location/read the install path for all versions or find a available folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by serveral others nested transactions are not supported in SQL Server. I have decided to minimize the number of state changing statements after the users code and that I clean those statements at the start of a test batch. This way it doesn't really matter that I can't rollback my own transaction, since the heavy lifting will be rolled back either by me or the user.

I also decided to fail the test when the starting @@TRANCOUNT and the ending @@TRANCOUNT dont match up so that no test can pass when there is something wrong with the users transactions.

The current system however will still struggle with a user doing a COMMIT TRAN. That is a problem for another time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible without any communication/rules for the user code. Despite what you do, if the user's code runs as many `COMMIT`s as there are `@@TRANCOUNT` at that time, the transaction will be commited and there will be nothing you can do about that.

One way you could do this is if you check/enforce the user code to, instead of using `COMMIT`, change that to `if @@TRANCOUNT>=2 COMMIT`. This will make sure the TRUE data commit can only be done by YOUR `COMMIT` command. Of course, it happens you never really want to commit, so you just `rollback` and it's over.

You mention:

> What I want is that if a user calls rollback only their part of the
>   transaction is rolled back

Please note that nested transactions are kind of a myth. Refer to [this excellent article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/). Long story short: "Nested" `BEGIN TRANSACTION`s and `COMMIT`s do actually nothing except change the value of the system var `@@TRANCOUNT` so that some organisation can be made through procedures.

Comment: I was looking for a way to simulate nested transactions, but if it is not possible I will consider forcing my users to use a transaction template.

Comment: I will also take a look to your suggestion of changing their code to add the trancount check

Comment: Forcing users to use a try/transaction/catch block is a solution which could take more time but is a good practice, generally. One possible would be Erland Sommerskog's: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern . Keep in mind though that, forcing the use of a block should mean banning the use of `commit` inside the functional code section, so it seems you cannot avoid that part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to rollback a part of transaction and keep the other transaction intact. The moment we rollback the transaction, the entire transaction gets rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual need is to write the test cases for T-SQL. If that is correct then I feel you don't have to reinvent the wheel and start using the open source test framework T-SQLT https://tsqlt.org/

Comment: I know about tsqlt, and I have pulled inspiration from it, the problem is that is does not support spy validation, proper code coverage nor mutation testing.